# Login app using MySQL database with Android Studio

Tags: php, android, mysql

As the title says, I'm trying to make my first android app with a simple login feature by fetching the username and password from a MySQL database but I'm getting the following error in logcat and my app crashes when I click on the login button

```
01-27 12:35:11.787 2509-2525/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: com.example.klm.sql, PID: 2509
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
at com.example.klm.sql.Background.doInBackground(Background.java:39)
at com.example.klm.sql.Background.doInBackground(Background.java:23)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Can somebody tell me what these errors mean?How can i solve it?

Comment: please attach the source file

Comment: follow this link for complete guidance http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm

Comment: Well, just look at you Log entries: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`. Then there is the exact line given: `at com.example.klm.sql.Background.doInBackground(Background.java:39)`. Apply a debugger and add some more specific information as well as code snippets.

Comment: Please show your `AsycTask` source code.

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it. All I had to do was change:

```
String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/login.php";
```

To:

```
String login_url = "https://10.0.2.2/login.php";
```

Comment: Some where you have wrong casting ,HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be  cast HttpsURLConnection, please correct it.Hope it will help you.